# Возможность давать ответы на вопрос, помеченный как требующий правки

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, ответы

В данном вопросе, автор добавил ответ на вопрос, после того как он был помечен *требующий правки*. Это баг?
[Скрипт для определения устройства пользователя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473356/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F)

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:**

Был найден способ, как это сделать:

1. Открываем форму добавления ответа.
2. В этот момент происходит изменение статуса вопроса на *Требует правки*, вполне возможно что при других будет тоже самое.
3. Пользователь нажимает опубликовать ответ, и ответ успешно публикуется.

Данный факт был проверен при участии @Nofate, @Bald56rus

Comment: @KromStern, Добавил картинку

Comment: @KromStern, а вы на тот ответ наводили? у указанного мной ответа дата _2015-12-10 08:09:51Z_

Comment: Виноват, не туда посмотрел

Comment: Больше похоже на исключение в случае, если отвечает автор вопроса

Comment: @PashaPash, [попробовали у кого был вопрос - не получилось](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26054640#26054640)

Comment: @PashaPash может проведем эксперимент, создадим вопрос и объявим требующим правки:) я могу задать такой вопрос :D

Comment: Мва-ха-ха! Что на называется, спасибо за информацию.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [How was this answer posted after this question was closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922/137096)

Comment: @jfs, забавно, но такая плашка у меня не всегда появлялась, и соответственно кнопка не отключалась

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Насколько я помню, возможность опубликовать ответ на уже закрытый вопрос создана специально, чтобы не огорчать тех, кто потратил свое время на написание ответа. Согласитесь, что будет неприятно, если вы потратите полчаса на хороший ответ, а вопрос в это время закроют.

Такие случаи хоть и нечасты, но встречаются. Например, на плохо оформленный вопрос натыкается эксперт, который может распознать проблему даже по обрывкам информации. Он пишет ответ, а в это время вопрос закрывают другие участники (воздержусь от обсуждения этой популярной в последнее время проблемы).

Вероятно, есть какой-то период, в течение которого ещё можно опубликовать ответ на закрытый вопрос. Предполагаю, что вы в своем эксперименте жали кнопку «опубликовать» сразу, как только вопрос закрывался. Если найду точное время — дополню ответ; если кто-то уже знает — правки всячески приветствуются.

Comment: В приведённом вопросе там разница на десятки минут. Я при тестировании конечно же столько не ждал

Comment: Насколько я знаю, просто пока открыта страница. Если её обновить, то возможность отвечать теряется. Тоже считаю, что это сделано намеренно.

Comment: [около 4 часов период](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91928/137096)

Comment: @Qwertiy возможно, что не пока страница открыта, а если есть сохранённый черновик ответа. Это только мои догадки.