# Что делать, если хочется опубликовать ответ на закрытый вопрос?

Tags: поддержка

Хочу добавить ответ в закрытый вопрос.

Но не нахожу кнопки для голосования за открытие вопроса, возможно у меня репутации на сайте не хватает.

Что делать, если хочется опубликовать ответ на закрытый вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос закрыт корректно. Голосовать за переоткрытие можно с 3000 реп.

Comment: Проголосовал за удаление всего вопроса. Рекомендации ПО, особенно без явно сформулированной решаемой задачи, не относятся к тематике StackOverflow. Не нужно дальше от неё отклоняться.

Comment: Мне из этой области нравится ресурс AlternativeTo, [где есть и про Avocode (и в списке есть Zeplin)](http://alternativeto.net/software/avocode/). Не реклама, сам никакого отношения к ним не имею, но неоднократно находил с его помощью занятные опенсорсины.

Comment: Здравствуйте всеt! Мой ответ корректный, и он может кому-нибудь помочь. Предлагаю его добавить тогда в закрытый вопрос(если это возможно), и пусть он дальше будет закрыт. Или удалить вопрос, как это предлагает D-side. Но точно не оставлять это как сейчас. Если человек не может добавить верный ответ на вопрос, зачем тогда вообще существует этот вопрос.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov уже удалили. Спасибо!

Comment: Теперь надо текущий вопрос удалить :)

Comment: Кто мне сюда поставил минусы - вы удивительные люди! Я написал ответ на вопрос и просто желал его опубликовать, и за это вы мне минусы поставили! Всего вам доброго! Согласен что данную тему тогда можно удалить. Но тот вопрос был корректный и мой ответ мог кому-нибудь помочь!

Comment: @alexolut или ответить на него, как на "что делать, если на закрытый вопрос очень хочется ответить". Но для этого его нужно обобщить до этого состояния.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov ^ сделаете?

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov голоса на Мете не влияют на репутацию. Когда кто-то голосует в минус, значит он не согласен с позицией автора и всё тут. Не переживайте.

Comment: D-side простите, не понял ваше предложение. Avocode, это популярная программа для верстки HTML шаблонов, аналоги которые я указал значительно менее известные, считаю что и вопрос и ответ могут быть полезны другим, и только. В любом случае, я все написал. Всего доброго!

Comment: @D-side а что тут можно ещё сделать кроме как переоткрыть? В этом и весь ответ будет. То есть и так всё понятно.

Comment: @alexolut стал бы я это предлагать, если бы всё было так просто :) Можно рассказать, почему ответ на закрытый вопрос оставлять не стоит.

Comment: @D-side ну да. Два варианта тогда: переоткрыть, смириться. :)

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov переформулировать вопрос в "что делать, если хочется опубликовать ответ на закрытый вопрос". Это хороший вопрос для Меты. Поиск альтернатив Avocode же тут лишь пример, и для самой Меты это оффтопик. Тем более что соответствующий вопрос на основном сайте уже удалён.

Comment: Связанный вопрос https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5890/23044

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вопрос закрыт, дать на него ответ не представляется возможным. При этом вопрос может быть закрыт по разным причинам. Если такая причина - "дубликат", то стоит посмотреть ответы на связанных вопросах. Может быть будет правильным дать ответ там, если ничего подобного еще не было озвучено. Если же ответ хочется предоставить именно для закрытого вопроса, единственный<sup>1</sup> способ сделать это - переоткрыть вопрос. Голосование за переоткрытие вопроса доступно, начиная с 3000 реп. Если у вас еще нет достаточной репутации, то можно отметить вопрос тревогой вида "привлечь внимание модератора", где подробно описать причину, по которой вы считаете, что вопрос требует переоткрытия. Когда (и если) вопрос будет переоткрыт, на него можно будет дать ответ. Также можно попробовать стимулировать процесс переоткрытия вопроса в [специальном чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32012/) или в [общем чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) (если вы не получили реакции в первом случае).

<sup>1</sup> ожидая, что вопрос будет закрыт, но пока он еще не закрыт, можно добавить ответ и тут же удалить его. Произведя таким образом некое "бронирование" ответа. Восстановить такой ответ можно будет и после того, как вопрос будет закрыт.

Comment: любопытный хак в сноске, не знал.

Comment: @AK Qwertiy этим грешит :)

Comment: @alexolut. ты еще забыл про [второй хак](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1971/186999)

Comment: всё же мне кажется, лишний раз отвлекать модераторов на переоткрытие вопросов не стоит

Comment: @mymedia почему "лишний"? Это их работа — обрабатывать флаги!