# Ответ требует правки связи с изменением стандарта

Tags: предложение, предлагаемые-правки

Господа программисты, лазая по сайту, я видел закрытие вопросы, на которые нельзя отвечать и вносить свою лепту в тему.
 Вы конечно зададитесь вопросом, а к чему это... Сейчас поясню.

У меня был вопрос на сайте, на который мне удачно ответили, коллега был очень грамотен и даже пояснил суть... 
[Вот ссылка на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706956/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0).

Мир не стоит на месте, все развивается, появляются новые технологии. Когда-то был стандарт javascript ECMA-3, сейчас уже все браузеры поддерживают ECMA-5 и уже на подходе шестая ECMA, и на сколько я знаю полностью не внедрена...

Так вот, если бы мой вопрос или подобный был задан когда ECMA-5 не была внедрена, то если вы пройдете по ссылке, то увидите, что мне бы пришлось городить кучу кода или искать обходные пути, но тут мне в помощь  внедрили LET в место VAR...  Все кто ответил мне на мой вопрос были правы по сути, но естественно я выбрал самый простой и легкий... (второй вариант ответа  Grundy) Так вот, если бы мой вопрос решился бы давно и тут на сайте начинающий программист видит вопрос, видит решение... а решение то старого стандарта и уже есть возможность решить вопрос более просто и легко.

я в курсе что закрытие вопросы можно открывать по новой, это могут сделать не все, а имеющие определенные статус. Не правильно ли будет внедрить кнопку что ли? Чтобы старожилы, модераторы  и админ обратили внимание.

> ОТВЕТ ТРЕБУЕТ ПРАВКИ СВЯЗИ С ИЗМЕНЕНИЕМ СТАНДАРТА...

Согласен, кнопка получилась длинной, ну суть я думаю вы поняли.

При этом, ни в коем случае изменение не должно отразиться на оценке старого ответа...

Если я правильно понял, сайт является не только просто местом общения коллег программистов и сисадминов,  а еще и кладовая готовых примеров для людей которые
ищут ответ на свой вопрос....
Скажу сразу, я не встречал еще ответы которые нужно изменить, я все же начинающий, но уверен, если грамотный и профессиональный программист покопается то точно найдет. 
И естественно данный вопрос касается, уверен не только JS, но и всех языков кроме тех которые не развиваются.

P.S.  К чему я привел ссылку на свой вопрос, отвечу, меня тут уже разок заблокировали, потому, что вопрос был не развернут и без конкретного примера

Comment: В приведенном примере у тебя скорее XY проблема, и стоит его наверное закрыть дубликатом [Почему асинхронная функция внутри цикла выполняет последнюю итерацию много раз?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433887/186999). В любом случае, никто не мешает дать дополнительный ответ, с решением, которое использует новый стандарт

Comment: вопрос, который вы выбрали в качестве примера не закрыт и никогда не был закрытым, [судя по истории](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/706956/timeline). Вы хотите обсудить как обновить *принятый* ответ?

Comment: вопрос не был закрыт, я привет пример, того что могло быть иначе...

Comment: программист, прежде чем делать проекты и писать что-то должен для начала прочитать книги по соответствующему языку программирования. В них всегда есть история ЯП, в них всегда есть примеры. И обычно, если были какие-то ранние стандарты — помечают что раньше можно было написать так-то, а теперь так-то. То есть не стоит ничего начинать писать пока 1) не прочтешь несколько книг по ЯП 2) не ознакомишься сам с версиями языка 3)  не ознакомишься с основными функциями и методами. Если человек приходит на SO для бездумного копирования и не удосужился узнать о новшествах — сугубо его проблемы

Comment: ну и как написал Grundy - если можешь привести ответ с новыми фишками - пиши, зачем остальных тревожить? а если их нет уже на ресурсе, то кто будет менять? модераторы? или другие участники, которым проще новый ответ написать, чем править?

Comment: я, изучаю js не давно, и столкнулся с проблемой этой...  начинающие не совсем имею представления о стандартах... это приходит со временем... я столкнулся с подобной проблемой на другом сайте и другом примере, а проблема то была не в коде, а стандарте...  надо делать все правильно... согласен... учить... читать...  но если пример будет содержать пояснения такого рода, намного легче будет... не будут возникать лишние вопросы и ненужные дискуссии

Comment: @Air `начинающие не совсем имею представления о стандартах.` - потому что вместо того, чтобы почитать книги по языку, они сразу хватаются за написание CRM и OS. Нет. Так дела не делаются. Если ты хочешь быть программистом, лучшим в сей области, то будь добр, ознакомься для начала с основами, почитай книги. Если  у них нет желания читать и узнать всю необходимую информацию, то значит им и не важны и какие-то там левые стандарты. А человек ознакомленный , который и правда увлечен и ознакомился с ЯП, сможет переработать предложенный код с одного стандарта в другой

Comment: *сайт является не только просто местом общения коллег программистов и сисадминов* -- не совсем. Для общения на Stack Overflow используются чаты, [вот наши](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=ru.stackoverflow.com). А на основном сайте полагается придерживаться вопросов-ответов и минимума комментариев.

Comment: да, и впрям....  говорят...  сытый голодного не разумеет.....

Comment: `да, и впрям.... говорят... сытый голодного не разумеет.....` - понимаете, есть голодные, кому предлагают работу, за которую заплатят и те смогут купить еды. Но те почему-то упорно отказываются и хотят просто хорошо кушать достав еды себе бесплатно, и, желательно, не вставая с дивана. Вот вы сейчас именно об этом. У людей весь интернет открыт и миллионы гектаров информации, в которой нужно сидеть и изучать, а вместо этого ждут чуда. Есть ощущение, что вы любите просто линейный копипаст и хотите чтобы остальные делали тоже самое. Однако, если это так, то может быть это и не их ремесло вовсе?

Comment: Лично я, прежде чем хоть как-то куда-то рыпаться что-то делать два года безвылазно сидел читал книги, до дыр протер эти чёртовы принципы ООП. Я не родился с понимаем их и с вложенными стандартами в голове. Потрачены десятки часов усвоения материала (и три сожжёных чайника, которые сгорали пока увлеченно читал материал). Так что не ясны ваши причитания по этому поводу.

Comment: кстати,  никогда в жизни не занимался копипастом, ни разу не использовал код, который не понимаю...   всегда использовал только свое...  я люблю знать, а не дурью маяться... так что тут вы не правы...

Comment: и еще, я из всей баталии понял, что если вопрос нормальный и ответы соотвествуют, то такие вопросы не закрываются? я вас правильно понял? это вопрос ко всем...

Comment: народ, стыдно не ошыбаться, стыдно не исправлять свои ошибки, должен признаться, что  понял в чем суть...  был не прав, я понял, что нормальные и адекватные вопросы не закрывают....  мое предложение прозвучало поидиотский....))))))))

Comment: Народ, у меня очень наглая просьба, уберите пару минусов с моих вопросов, я не могу задавать вопросы, на дню по нескольку раз меняется ситуация.  PashaPash, убрал один минус на сколько я знаю, и я мог писать, не успел вопрос начать писать, кто то мне пару минусов понаставил, на вполне нормальные вопросы.  что за правило два вопроса с отрицательным статусом и все баста, нет возможности писать вопросы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если [вопрос *закрыт*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) на Stack Overflow — это значит (за некоторыми исключениями: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates), канонические [списки ссылок на ресурсы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/23044)), что он [не подходит для данного сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) (почему не подходит, причина закрытия может подсказать). Такие [вопросы вообще могут быть удалены автоматически](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293/23044).

Пример в вашем вопросе <strike>не закрыт ещё и [не был закрыт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/706956/timeline)</strike> — закрыт как дубликат.

Если вопрос закрыт как дубликат, то обновления/исправления ошибок следует в ответах к оригинальному вопросу помещать, а не в закрытом вопросе — это как раз одна из причин, по которой вопросы закрываются как дубликаты: чтобы обновления, новые решения в одном месте собирать.

*На закрытые вопросы, до тех пор пока они не будут исправлены и открыты, нельзя по определению отвечать.* Они не соответствуют правилам сайта. Если вы считаете, что вопрос незаслуженно закрыт, то голосуйте за переоткрытие, внесите правку, которая приведёт в соответствие с правилами сайта вопрос, оставьте комментарий с уточняющими вопросами к автору, чтобы улучшить вопрос, сами внесите улучшающую правку, если уверены, создайте обсуждение на Мета об открытии вопроса (с вашими доводами). См. [Что делать, если я не согласен с закрытием вопроса? Как его открыть снова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

Если вы хотите поделиться какой-либо полезной информацией, вы можете [задать новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (который соответствует правилам сайта) и сами на него ответить — [это явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

---

Если ваш вопрос как обновить [*принятый* ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), если он явно устарел, то опубликуйте новый ответ, добавьте комментарий к принятому ответу с упоминанием лучшего по вашему мнению решения и для популярных вопросов, в которых очень много ответов, если есть полная уверенность, то можно наверху принятого ответа добавить комментарий типа: *"решение X устарело, начиная с версии Y следует использовать Z. См. <ссылка на ответ с новым решением>"*

Если вы опубликуете хороший ответ, то спустя время голосование может поднять ваш вопрос наверх относительно других ответов — в этом одна из задач голосования. Можно также автора попросить сменить принятый ответ.

Если не можете сами обновлённый ответ опубликовать, то см. [Что делать, если у меня возник вопрос, который уже был задан, но ответ на него отсутствует?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5829/23044)

В тех случаях когда популярный ответ не просто устарел, но и является откровенно вредным (к примеру, рекомендация eval() с пользовательским вводом, когда это не нужно), то наличие нового ответа, минусов, комментария и предупреждения в старом ответе может быть недостаточно. В этом случае можно автора попросить удалить ответ. См. [Implement a way to "deprecate" Answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314172/4279).

Comment: при чем, тут мой пример?

Comment: @Air: Это у вас нужно спросить. Я тоже не понимаю какое отношение ваш пример имеет к вашему предложению.

Comment: к тому имеет, что если бы этот вопрос бы задан 10 лет назад, решение было бы другим...  и ксли бы я искал ответ на свой вопрос, то взял бы старый вариант ответа...а есть новый и простой....

Comment: причем тут закрыт мой вопрос или нет...  это примет возможного развития события

Comment: @Air это к вам вопрос. Это "возможное развитие событий" возможно для любого вопроса, и ваш пример не даёт нового повода для переоткрытия. Зачем этот конкретный сценарий вообще упомянут в вопросе, непонятно.

Comment: я о любом вопросе и говорю....  при чем тут я))))))?????

Comment: @Air: ну так добавьте ваш *"новый и простой"* вариант— кто вам мешает? Дочитайте мой ответ до фразы: *"Если вы хотите поделиться какой-либо полезной информацией"*

Comment: @Air ну как это "при чём". Вопрос же ваш? :)

Comment: так, слушайте, когда я писал эту статью или вопрос, то тот вопрос дубликатом отмечен не был, это после этого вопроса, на него обратили внимание и отметили дубликатом....  кстати как я понял, кто ответил на него точнее и лучше, он и отметил)))...  черт с ним с этом вопросом....   )))

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что Вы рекомендуете не трогать никак существующие и устаревшие ответы, если вопрос, для которого они даны, закрыт как дубликат?

Comment: @alexout: *«это как раз одна из причин, по которой вопросы закрываются как дубликаты: чтобы обновления, новые решения в одном месте собирать.»* Если вы считаете какой-либо ответ особенно вредным, то можно ссылку на новый ответ добавить как выше описано для принятых ответов.¶ Стоит упомянуть что для незалогиненных посетителей автоматический redirect стоит (они не увидят дубликат и его ответы).

Answer (score 8):

Вы предлагаете привлечь внимание к вопросам, которые уже решены, но стали бы лучше от появления в них ответов про новые стандарты? Я правильно понимаю вашу идею?

Тогда существующие ответы трогать не нужно. **Лучше привлечь новые.** Опытные читатели Stack Overflow знают, что кроме ответа с галочкой* стоит ознакомиться ещё и с ответом, имеющим максимальный рейтинг. И с остальными тоже неплохо бы, по убыванию рейтинга, пока не надоест или ответы не закончатся. Поэтому реагировать на введение в строй новых стандартов на SO принято добавлением новых ответов с современными решениями.

А для привлечения новых ответов по какой бы там ни было причине уже реализован штатный механизм, доступный практически всем:

#### Проявите инициативу и [объявите конкурс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) на 50+ собственной репутации!

При объявлении конкурса есть возможность указать собственную причину (а-ля *"необходимо более современное решение, существующие используют устаревшие стандарты"*), которая будет указана в конкурсной плашке под вопросом.

Вопрос попадёт в [особый список "конкурсных вопросов"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured), и получит дополнительное внимание от посетителей. А "приз" послужит дополинтельной мотивацией для отвечающих.

---

Если собственной репутации не хватает на достойный конкурс, то не всё потеряно.

Иногда можно встретить участников, готовых жертвовать собственной репутацией с целью привлечь дополнительный хороший материал или дополнительное внимание к хорошему материалу. Можно изложить свою идею [в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) и поинтересоваться, нет ли желающих её спонсировать из своей репутации (коей у активных участников, как правило, с лихвой).

---

PS: не знаю, при чём тут закрытые вопросы, но закрывают их определённо не по той причине, что стандарты, о которых в них речь, слишком стары. Посему, введение новых стандартов не является поводом для переоткрытия.

* А галочку ставит один вполне конкретный человек (ТС, автор вопроса), после чего убрать её кроме него же не может вообще никто, даже модераторы. И никто не застрахован от размещения галочки на плохом или вовсе неверном ответе.

Comment: Добавлю: если вопрос - ваш собственный, то начинать проявлять инициативу нужно со снятия галочки.

Comment: А еще полезно смотреть на даты ответов, если все ответы от 11 года, например, и один с плюсами от 16, то в нем могут быть дельные "современные" детали или способ решения.

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том, что ответ не может требовать правки, по крайней мере в том смысле, в котором "требуют правки" некоторые вопросы.

"Требует правки" на вопросе означает, что 
- этот вопрос не соответствуюет правилам сайта
- для соответствия правилам сайта требуется правка именно от автора вопроса, и никто кроме него внести эту правку не может.

Очевидно, что такое "требование правки" неприменимо к ответам - от появления нового стандарта ответ не перестает быть верным и применимым. Менять чужие ответы под новые стандарты нельзя (за исключением wiki-ответов). Требовать правки от авторов ответа - тем более (автор и так потратил время на ответ, он никому ничего не должен).

Что стоит сделать при устаревании ответа:

- Добавить комментарий, что есть новый способ решения проблемы
- Оформить новый способ решения проблемы в виде нового ответа в той же теме

В совсем запущенных случаях, когда ответ устарел значительно или когда есть множество разрозненных вопросов с разными вариантами ответов под разные версии стандарта / фреймворка / etc. - стоит собрать их все в месте в виде одного вопроса / ответа с отметкой wiki.

Comment: речь не о том что бы править ответ... речь о том, что бы дополнить, и вопрос если закрыт, то можно было бы его открыть, и просто поставить галочку, что обратите внимание, вопрос можно дополнить ответом...

Comment: @Air если вопрос закрыт - значит он требует правки от автора. Если вопрос можно открыть без правки со стороны именно автора - он должен быть открыт. Т.е. вопросы, которые "можно дополнить ответом" не должны быть закрыты в принципе.

Comment: @PashaPash: ваш последний комментарий мне кажется является сутью ответа на данное предложение (стоит его в сам ответ, ближе к началу поместить)

Comment: @jfs может быть, но я до сих пор не понимаю, какое отношение закрытие вопроса имеет в отметке ответов как устаревших

Answer (score 0):

Господа, я понимаю, что ложка дорога к обеду, но все же. Я не люблю когда меня не понимают, то что вы меня не поняли, это моя проблема, а не ваша. Я нашел конкретный пример, по которому хочу показать, что я имел ввиду.

Я не правильно понял, тут моя вина.  Я подумал, что, если на вопрос ответили, то значит, его закрывают, как окончательный вариант, вы уж простите. Конечно глупо, я понимаю, что в век технологий нет предела совершенству и прогрессу и в программировании не может быть окончательного варианта.

Вот ссылка на пример.[Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/162933/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-js-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-before-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-after/720175#720175). 
 Суть мною сказанного, в том, что если бы этот пример был закрыт, то стоило бы его открыть.   И дать еще одни ответ с вариантом. Этот вопрос задан, за долго, до того, как я узнал что такое HTML, CSS и JS.   Я не выяснял, можно было бы решить этот вопрос так, как я решил его сегодня, когда он был задан, не суть.

P.S.  Я не искал пример, просто на него наткнулся случайно и тут мое 
самолюбие и решило объясниться.  Согласитесь, если  бы было так как я подумал, то мое предложение звучало бы актуально и не глупо.

Comment: я надеюсь, вы меня правильно поймете...